# "He was unfortunate enough to be involved in a car accident"

Tags: grammaticality

Regardless of whether there are better ways to form this sentence (and most definitely shorter) I want to know if its grammatically correct. I know "fortunate enough to" is possible (He was fornunate enough to win the lottery) but is this as well or does it sound weird?

Comment: It sounds just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you think  he was unfortunate to the degree that he was involved in a car accident, then go ahead with your sentence; it's grammatical.  But if you mean he was fortunate to the degree that he was not involved in a car accident, then your sentence is not correct.  Instead, you should say:

He was fortunate enough not to be involved in a car accident.

Answer (score 1):

I found an example sentence similar to yours on the Merriam Webster dictionary website:

"She was unfortunate enough to have been chosen as an example."

So, I think it's safe to say that it's a grammatically sound sentence. I don't think any English speaker would have a problem understanding what you're saying.